# Boundedness for derivatives of monotonically increasing functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, monotone-functions

For any $n\in \mathbb{N}$ let $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to [0,1]$ be a monotonincally increasing function fulfilling $\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} f_n(x)=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} f_n(x)=1$. Furthermore $f_n(x)\leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x<0$ and $f_n(x)\geq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x\geq 0$. $f_n$ being montone it is also differentiable almost everywhere and defines a measure.
Can I bound $||f_n'||$ somehow ?

Comment: Short answer: No, no way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That  depends on what norm you have in mind when you say $||f_n'||$. If $\mu_n$ is the measure "defined by" $f_n$ (that is, $f(x)-f(-\infty)=\mu_n((-\infty,x))$)) then the total variation norm of $\mu_n$ is $$||\mu_n||=\mu_n(\Bbb R)=f_n(\infty)-f_n(-\infty)=1.$$And the pointwise derivative is just the absolutely continuous part of $\mu_n$, hence the $L^1$ norm satisfies $$||f_n'||_1\le||\mu_n||=1.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was very helpful!

Comment: Is $\mu_n$ with $\mu_n(A)=\int_{A} f_n'(x) dx$ not a measure itself, so that I get the equality of the norm ? I think I misused the notation. By $||f_n'||$ I already meant the norm of the measure...

Comment: @user99432 Yes, if $\nu_n(A)=\int_A f_n'$ then $\nu_n$ is a measure. But it's not the same as $\mu_n$, in fact $\nu_n$ is just the absolutely continuous part of $\mu_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the norm you are using.

---

If you are using the uniform norm, then the answer is no. Take $$f_n(x) = \frac{e^{nx}}{e^{nx} + 1}.$$

You have that $f_n'(0) = \frac{n}{2}$, which is clearly unbounded.

---

If you are using the $L^1$ norm, then you can show that $\|f_n'\| \leq 1$, so the answer is yes.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful!

Comment: @user99432  Don't forget to *accept* one of the answers you got.

Comment: I tried to show that the sequence $f_n$ is bounded: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4101968/how-to-show-boundedness-of-a-sequence-in-bv , how can I see that the integral over $f_n'$ is the absolute continuous part ? Since $\mu_n$ is a measure, I can decompose $\mu_n$ into an absolute continuous and singular part. Is it obvious, that the absolute continuous part is really the integral over $f_n'$?